# Monosyllabic and polysyllabic

Tags: meaning

what exactly would monosyllabic words and polysyllabic words be? Google definition isn't helping to understand...

Comment: See [What is a word called that has more than one syllable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/753/what-is-a-word-called-that-has-more-than-one-syllable)

Comment: What exactly is throwing you?  Other than just repeating the definition (monosyllabic = made up of one syllable, polysyllabic = made up of multiple syllables), I'm not sure what to tell you.

Answer (score 3):

`Mono` means "one", `poly` means "many".  So monosyllabic words have one syllable (e.g. "is", "it", "a", "cow", "through"), whereas polysyllabic words have multiple syllables (e.g. "falcon", "syllable", "throughout").

Comment: Examples chosen at random.

Comment: I was wandering how dip you know the Greek Language, because I see that you're approach this Language from a very good point of view

Comment: @Lefteris I've just always been interested in language, especially the Greek and Latin influences on words. I notice the relationships pretty easily, but I haven't really studied it or anything.

Comment: I'm tremendously impressed from your interest, because the Greek Language is the only (I thing) Language which gives you the opportunity to play with words and meanings, play like a game, it's really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

*Monosyllabic* is *polysyllabic*. *Polysyllabic* is *polysyllabic*. *Is* is *monosyllabic*.

Comment: As if the poor OP weren't confused enough already.

Answer (score 1):

- Monosyllabic words have exactly one syllable.
- Polysyllabic words have more than one syllable.